# Bootstrap glyphicons not loading while other classes are working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have added bootstrap using nuget package . Added link to the bootstrap stylesheet but glyphicons are not loading .Please help.
`

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.3/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@angular/router@0.2.0/angular1/angular_1_router.js"></script>
    <script src="../scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />   <meta charset="utf-8" /> </head> <body ng-app="moviesList">
    <h1>Movie List Application</h1>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
    <div ng-view>

    </div> </body> </html>
```

`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to load your css in header and js in footer section
And use maxcdn links for bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
    </head> 
    <body ng-app="moviesList">
        <h1>Movie List Application</h1>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
        <div ng-view></div> 
    </body> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.3/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@angular/router@0.2.0/angular1/angular_1_router.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: The issue here is that when we use local copy of bootstrap than the css folder and the fonts folder which has glyphicon images should be siblings.Later on it is relative.Using the CDN also works as we don't have to care about above relationship.